# Quicksort, first element as pivot , quick code check

Tags: python, quicksort

Trying to do quicksort, with first element of the list as the pivot.

Have been over this for hours, and just cannot find my mistake.

```
def quickSort(aList, l, r):
    #global count
    if l < r:
        swap = l+1
        for run in range (l+1,r):            
            if aList[l] > aList[run]:
                aList[swap],aList[run]=aList[run],aList[swap]
                swap += 1
            run += 1
        aList[l],aList[swap]= aList[swap],aList[l]
        quickSort(aList, l, swap-1)
        quickSort(aList, swap+1, r)


testl=[4,6,3,7,2]
print testl
quickSort(testl,0,len(testl)-1)
print testl
```

Output is :

[4, 6, 3, 7, 2]

[3, 6, 4, 2, 7]
Anyone see where i went wrong ? The pivot element seems to be at the right place but other than that idk :(

Comment: Why is there a global declaration for a variable you *aren't even using?!* What debugging have you done; what is the shortest failing example?

Comment: You mean count ? i just didnt delete that yet.. should count the number of comparisons .. but its pointless if the sorting does not even work. Even with 3 numbers it does not work :(

Comment: Please read [mcve] - that's a dead giveaway that you haven't bothered to prune your code down to only what's needed to recreate the issue.

Comment: I hope my edits make it better

Comment: Assigning to `pivot` won't change the list. Try `aList[l],aList[swap]= aList[swap],aList[l]`; but there seem to be more problems.

Comment: Thank you, yes it still does not work.. but your correction was very helpful !

Comment: Also, the assignment to `run` at the end of the loop does not do anything, as it's set by the for loop immediately afterwards.

Comment: english is not my first language . Do you mean run+=1 does not correctly increase to step through the list? or that i can just delete that line , since run will be increased in the for loop anyway

Comment: I suggest you liberally pepper your code with print statements and/or use e.g. http://www.pythontutor.com/ to visualise its operation. Your current logic has at least two flaws.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code can't handle a case like this:

```
2 5 3 7 6
```

In this case the pivot is less that all other elements so `swap` must not change (you change it before the loop) and we sort the rest. Also you don't need to increment `run` in the loop. I changed your code like bellow and now it works. One more thing, if you write `range(l+1,r)` you miss the last element. because you are calling the function like this: `quickSort(testl,0,len(testl)-1)`

```
def quickSort(aList, l, r):
    #global count
    if l < r:
        swap = l
        for run in range (l+1,r+1):            
            if aList[l] > aList[run]:
                swap += 1
                aList[swap],aList[run]=aList[run],aList[swap]

            #run += 1
        aList[l],aList[swap]= aList[swap],aList[l]
        quickSort(aList, l, swap-1)
        quickSort(aList, swap+1, r)
```

Answer (score -1):

Modified your code as below

```
def quickSort(aList, l, r):
  if l < r:
    swap = l+1
    pivot = aList[l]
    for run in range (l+1,r):
        if pivot > aList[run]:
          aList[swap],aList[run] = aList[run],aList[swap]
          swap+=1

    aList[l],aList[swap-1] = aList[swap-1],aList[l]
    quickSort(aList, l, swap-1)
    quickSort(aList, swap, r)
return aList


test = [4,6,3,7,2]
t = quickSort(test,0,len(test))
print t
```

Comment: So... what have you changed, and *why*?